# Docker Compose Redis It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, redis

I have tried dockerization asp.net 6, redis and postgresql with docker compose and I get the following error.

> The timeout was reached before the message could be written to the output buffer, and it was not sent, command=PING, timeout: 5000, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: CheckingForTimeout, serverEndpoint: redis_image:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: 127d47c5ce33(SE.Redis-v2.5.61.22961), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=12,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=0,Free=32767,Min=12,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=12,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=1665), v: 2.5.61.22961 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

[My Github Repo](https://github.com/Filiphasan/MediatrExample)

My Dockerfile for Asp.Net 6

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MediatrExample.API/MediatrExample.API.csproj", "MediatrExample.API/"]
COPY ["MediatrExample.CQRS/MediatrExample.CQRS.csproj", "MediatrExample.CQRS/"]
COPY ["MediatrExample.Service/MediatrExample.Service.csproj", "MediatrExample.Service/"]
COPY ["MediatrExample.Data/MediatrExample.Data.csproj", "MediatrExample.Data/"]
COPY ["MediatrExample.Core/MediatrExample.Core.csproj", "MediatrExample.Core/"]
COPY ["MediatrExample.Shared/MediatrExample.Shared.csproj", "MediatrExample.Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MediatrExample.API/MediatrExample.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MediatrExample.API"
RUN dotnet build "MediatrExample.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MediatrExample.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
EXPOSE    5000
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MediatrExample.API.dll"]
```

My Docker Compose yml file

```yaml
version: '3.4'

networks:
    mediatrexample:
        driver: bridge

services:
    pgsql_image:
        image: postgres:latest
        container_name: postgersql_db
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "123456"
            POSTGRES_DB: "ecommerce"
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        networks:
            - mediatrexample

    redis_image:
        image: 'redis:latest'
        container_name: redis_db
        restart: always
        environment:
            - REDIS_PASSWORD=RRnFPZ93tjBHB9W62p
            - REDIS_PORT=6380
        ports:
            - '6380:6379'
        command: [ "redis-server" ]
        networks:
            - mediatrexample

    mediatrexample.api:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mediatrexampleapi
        container_name: mediatr_example
        depends_on:
            - pgsql_image
            - redis_image
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: MediatrExample.API/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - mediatrexample
        links:
            - pgsql_image
            - redis_image
        environment:
            - CONNECTIONSTRINGS__NpgSQLConnection=User ID=postgres;Password=123456;Host=pgsql_image;Port=5432;Database=ecommerce
            - Redis__Host=redis_image
            - Redis__Port=6380
            - Redis__Password=RRnFPZ93tjBHB9W62p
```

My ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect Code is in Program.cs

```cs
var multiplexer = RedisUtility.ConnectRedis(Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(multiplexer);
```

My RedisUtility.ConnectRedis Code is

```cs
public static class RedisUtility
    {
        public static ConnectionMultiplexer ConnectRedis(IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            var redisOptions = ConfigurationOptions.Parse($"{Configuration["Redis:Host"]}:{Configuration["Redis:Port"]}");
            redisOptions.Password = Configuration["Redis:Password"];
            redisOptions.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
            var multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisOptions);
            return multiplexer;
        }
    }
```

My Redis Service Class is and Lifecycle is Singleton

```cs
public class RedisCacheService : IRedisCacheService
    {
        private IDatabase _database;
        private static IConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;
        public RedisCacheService(IConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer)
        {
            _connectionMultiplexer = connectionMultiplexer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionMultiplexer));
            _database = _connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase(0);
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
        {
            return default;
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task SetAsync<T>(string key, T value, int expiredInMinute = 120)
        {
            //RedisKey key1 = new RedisKey(key);
            //var valueStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
            //RedisValue redisValue = new RedisValue(valueStr);
            //await _database.StringSetAsync(key1, redisValue, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(expiredInMinute));
            var pong = await _database.PingAsync();
        }
    }
```

I have tried many solutions such as SSL=True, Tls12, Different Version Stackexchange.Redis, but I cant find why stackexchange.redis doesn't connect redis. I tried to connect redis with Another Redis Desktop Manager app and its success connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with port

```
- Redis__Port=6380
```

when you are in docker network you should use internal port, not the one which is exposed for outside.
it should be

```
- Redis__Port=6379
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. you are right. docker network should use internal port. Solved.

Comment: Happy to help. kindly accept this answer if your problem is solved.